# How to split data every n-th character and make it into array in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports

i want to split data to make it into array. so given for example: 12345678

i want to get string array like this => ["234","678"]

is it possible in crystal report?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. But the requirements are not clear.

Data type of input (string or Number?)

Logic: discard 1st character? Then, groups of 3 skipping the 4th character?

Comment: yes, i have to discard 1st and 4th character. Data type is string

Comment: I want to try using split, but can't find the right delimiter. Because the data is 300 random character

Answer (score 0):

Here is formula code that takes "12345678" and returns "^234^678":

```
local stringvar myString := "12345678";
local stringvar myDelimitedString := "";
local numbervar StringLength := Len(myString);
local numbervar i;

For i := 1 to StringLength step 4 do 
myDelimitedString := myDelimitedString + "^" + MID(myString, i+ 1, 3);

myDelimitedString;
```